# Confusing Behaviors in Sorting with C++ vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, mergesort

I just begin to program in C++ and I meet some confusing results when implementing a mergeSort algorithm with std::vector.
I used to program in Python and Java. It is the first time I use C++. Besides, I search for some information about reference and pointer. But it does not solve my problem.

```cpp
void merge(vector<int>& arr, int low, int mid, int high){
    vector<int> tmp;
    int left = low;
    int right = mid + 1;
    while (left <= mid && right <= high)
    {
        if (arr[left] < arr[right])
        {
            tmp.push_back(arr[left]);
            left ++;
        } else
        {
            tmp.push_back(arr[right]);
            right ++;
        }
    }
    while (left <= mid)
    {
        tmp.push_back(arr[left]);
        left ++;   
    }
    while (right <= high)
    {
        tmp.push_back(arr[right]);
        right ++;
    }
    for (int i = low; i <= high; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = tmp[i];
    }
}

void mergeSort(vector<int> arr, int start, int tail){
    if (start >= tail)
    {
        return;
    }
    int mid = start + (tail - start)/2;
    mergeSort(arr, start, mid);
    mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, tail);
    merge(arr, start, mid, tail);
    // Here, I want to see the process
    print_vec(arr);
    cout<<"==================="<<endl;
}

int main(){
    vector<int> arr{6,7,1,3,5,7,4};
    mergeSort(arr, 0, arr.size() - 1);
    print_vec(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```sh
6 7 1 3 5 7 4 
===================
6 7 655696 0 5 7 4 
===================
1 3 6 7 5 7 4 
===================
6 7 1 3 5 7 4 
===================
6 7 1 3 0 -1 -1112271603 
===================
5 6 7 4 7 1 3 
===================
6 7 1 3 5 7 4
```

I do not understand why the program generates some weird numbers such as "655696, -1112271603, -1".

I have tested the "merge" function. It seems correct.

It is really exotic to debug this. I even do not know how to search for this problem on Google. So I ask it here.

Comment: What is your debugger saying? What about this line: `arr[i] = tmp[i];`? Are you sure you want to throw away `tmp[0], ... tmp[low - 1]` elements?

Comment: `void mergeSort(vector<int> arr, ...` takes the vector by value -- use a reference instead.

Comment: Use half-open interval and keep your sanity

Comment: Aside: you know that `tmp` will have `high - low + 1` elements, you may as well `reserve` that up front

Comment: You may also consider accepting a helpful answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major issues in your code:

First, your `mergeSort` takes its vector argument *by value*, which means that any action it performs on that vector will be lost when the function returns. To fix this, pass that argument *by reference*:

```cpp
void mergeSort(vector<int>& arr, int start, int tail) // Pass "arr" by reference
{
    //...
```

Second, the last `for` loop of your `merge` function is attempting to use the same indexes for both its *given* array (`arr`) and its *local* array (`tmp`); this is not correct, and will result in attempting to access out-of-bounds elements of `tmp`, causing undefined behaviour (the weird values you see).

The index used for the `tmp` array should start at **zero**. So, to fix the issue, add a second loop variable (let's call it `j`) to the loop, initialize that to zero, and increment it as with the `i` index at the end of each loop:

```cpp
void merge(vector<int>& arr, int low, int mid, int high)
{
    //
    // Other code as is ...
    //
    for (int i = low, j = 0; i <= high; i++, j++) {
        arr[i] = tmp[j]; // The "tmp" elements will ALWAYS start from ZERO
    }
}
```

One other note: for indexes of STL containers (like `std::vector`), and return values of member functions like `.size()`, you really should be using the `size_t` type rather than `int`. Your compiler will no doubt warn you about this, if you let it: clang gives me lots of the following:

> warning : implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to
> 'std::vector::size_type' (aka 'unsigned long long')
> [-Wsign-conversion]

Comment: Thank you, my friend. It really helps me a lot!